# get Form Id from the Request in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, httpwebrequest

How can I get "form" ID from the posted Request? Is there a way to do it? Or just parameters are send?
I have tried Request.["id"], but I just get the value of the parameter with that name.
`Request.Form[****]`

Comment: If you are looking for form id attribute, try sending the name via hidden form

Answer (score 0):

I think thats a weird question because as soon my page post data I already know which button got activate with calling the Sender in the function below

```
public void clickbutton(Control sender, EventArgs e)
```

from there its easy to determine which button got selected also by calling the

```
((Button)sender).ID
```

so if you know which button got triggered, you also know which form did a postback.